# basic programming keeping track of objects java

Tags: java, object, static

public Person (String name, int age, boolean isFemale)

In a program I am writing I have to keep track of how many Person objects are created. I also have to make static variables for the combined ages of all the Persons as well as how many of them are female. If someone could at least point me in the right direction thatd be awesome I have no idea how to do this step.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add some `static` fields to your class, that will be updated in constructor when new Person object is created. `static` fields are common for all instances of a same class.

For example:

```
private static personCount;
private static femaleCount;
public Person (String name, int age, boolean isFemale){
    personCount++
    ...
}
```

Fill ... with missing code for counting females.

Comment: We can only assume user987339's female counting algorithm is proprietary :)

Comment: Gender is irrelevant these days :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, you pointed me in the right direction and I was able to figure it all out. This is my code- youll have to teach me how to insert snippets like you did
 public Person (String name, int age, boolean isFemale) {
  if (name == null)
  name = "Unknown";  
  this.name = name;
 
  this.age = age;
  
  totalAge += age;
   
  this.isFemale = isFemale;
  if (isFemale == true)
   totalFemales++;
  
  
  totalPersons++;
  
 }